# What to attach event listener to in Drupal behavior

Tags: 7, event-subscribers, javascript

I have a use case where I need to listen to the insertIntoActiveEditor event in the [insertIntoActiveEditor event](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/insert/tree/insert.js?h=7.x-1.x#n94) in the [Insert](https://drupal.org/project/insert) module, but with this code:

```
(function ($) {

/**
 * Custom behavior to generate image style derivatives on S3 when an image is
 * inserted into the WYSWIYG editor.
 */
Drupal.behaviors.generateDerivative = {
  attach: function(context, settings) {
    $(document).on('insertIntoActiveEditor', function(event, data) {
      var test = 'a';

    })
  }
}
})(jQuery);
```

I'm getting an error that says

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function
```

on this line

```
$(document).on('insertIntoActiveEditor', function(event, data) {
```

I thought I had that syntax correct, but apparently I don't. Do I need to change my selector to be the Insert button (the same as is used in the module JS)? I"ve tried changing it to

```
$('input[value="Insert"]').on('insertIntoActiveEditor', function(event, data) {
```

but I still get the same error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause was pretty basic - this is in the admin theme, which in Drupal 7 is set to use jQuery 1.4.4, and .on() wasn't added until 1.7. I switched to using .bind(), and it works fine now.